# How can I connect ACL node js roles with users from database MySQL (sequelize)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, acl, node-acl

I have MySQL database created with Sequelize. Now I want to give roles to users from that database with node acl. 
This is my acl.js file:

```
var acl = require('acl');
var aclSeq = require('acl-sequelize');
var sequelize = require('../models/index.js');

//acl
acl = new acl(new aclSeq(sequelize.connection, { prefix: 'acl_' })); 

acl.addUserRoles(4, 'admin');

acl.allow('admin', 'ourdogs', 'view')

module.exports = acl;
```

The problem is that it creates new databases acl_roles and acl_users but I want to connect users from my existing database "user"

```
id, username, email, password_digest, firstName, lastName, image, EmployeeId (columns)
'4', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', 'a', 'Admin', NULL,    'http://interworldgems.com/client_login/admin/images/login_icon.png', NULL
```

And after that call this method which will be allowed just for admin

```
  app.get('/ourdogs', acl.middleware(), function(req, res) {
    models.Dog.findAll().then(function(dogs) {
      res.render('ourdogs/ourdogs', { 
        title: 'Our dogs', 
        dogs: dogs 
      });
    })
  });
```

By running this code ACL creates these databases

"acl_roles"

```
key, value (columns)
admin, [4]
```

"acl_users"

```
key, value (columns)
4, ["admin"]
```

I know my code from acl.js is not correct but I don't know how to connect users from my database and then add them roles with acl. I was looking documentation but I couldn't find anything about this.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

ACL doesn't handle authentication.  ACL middleware performs a check like the following:

```
acl.isAllowed(req.session.userId, '/ourdogs', 'get')
```

For it to work you must have already populated *req.session.userId*.  It will check for permission to *req.method*, so you must assign this permission as well.